# Forbid any methods except interface method

Tags: php

I want to forbid any other methods in class except methods which implemented by interface.

For sample:

```
    interface Helper_Interface_AdminSinglePage {

    public function action_index();

    /**
     * AJAX save
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function action_save();

    /**
     * AJAX delete
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function action_delete();
}
```

Do you have any idea or maybe even solution?
I can figure it out by myself, just need some suggestions.

Comment: But why do you even need to do that?

Comment: There's not a particularly nice way to do this - you'd need to use reflection to analyse classes at runtime and throw exceptions if any "unauthorised" methods exist. Why do you need to? As the interface author, you shouldn't care *how* the methods are implemented, or indeed which other interfaces are implemented by the same class. That's really the point. If you want to force a more concrete implementation, you should be providing the class itself.

Comment: I have strict architecture, and I'd like to see, that juniors are following this way without unexpected behavior.

Comment: which " unexpected behavior"? you probably don't want an interface: you want a final class where you can pass a callback to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want an interface. You want a `final` class with that api, where the client pass the behavior as a callback that your class can call. Something like:

```
final class AdminSinglePage
{
    private $index;
    private $save;
    private $delete;

    public function __construct(Closure $index, Closure $save, Closure $delete)
    {
        $this->index = $index;
        $this->save = $save;
        $this->delete = $delete;
    }

    public function action_index()
    {
        call_user_func_array($this->save, []);
    }

    public function action_save()
    {
        call_user_func_array($this->save, []);
    }

    public function action_delete()
    {
        call_user_func_array($this->delete, []);
    }
}
```

that can be instantiate like this:

```
$page = new AdminSinglePage(function() {
    echo 'index page';
}, function() {
    echo 'save page';
}, function() {
    echo 'delete page';
});

// use it
$page->action_save();
```